# Add Force teleporting the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to push back my player when it collides with an object but when it collide with the object, it just teleporting back rather then pushing smoothly. I tweaked with values like Mass, Drag  on player's rigidbody or knockbackStrenght value from script. It just teleporting further positions with higher values and teleporting to closer positions with lower values but it always teleports not pushback.

My code on the object that will push back player looks like:

```html
public class StickRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float rotateSpeed;
    [SerializeField] float knockbackStrenght;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 rotateDir;

    Vector3 _parentPos;

    void Start()
    {
        _parentPos = GetComponentInParent<Transform>().position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(_parentPos, rotateDir, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce
                (Vector3.back * knockbackStrenght, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

[Player's rigidbody settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuGE7.png)

[When player collide with stick, it just teleporting back rather then pushing back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irsZ9.png)

Comment: Code looks ok, but mass 1 and drag 0 is very low, try increasing them e.g. mass 50, drag 0.5. Also, try a different `ForceMode`. Finally, is there any other code affecting the object?

Comment: I find out that Animator component on the player causing the issue. Unticking 'Apply root motion' seems solved my problem but now when player pushing back smoothly, its jittering. How can i deal with it?

Comment: What is the animation doing? Walking forward?

Comment: Its a walking forward animation (in-place) that I downloaded from Mixamo and here are the Rig and Animation settings that im using for the animation. https://freeimage.host/i/Srh6Sj  https://freeimage.host/i/SrhsAQ

Comment: Are you using a NavMeshAgent? If so, temporarily disable it, or reduce it's speed to zero.

Comment: No, Im not but there is a code on player that updates transform.position to move it forward every frame. I added a coroutine that stops this mechanic for a while when it collide with stick then return.  Jittering decreased but not gone entirely. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @absinthe's comment, you could try using rigidbody.velocity instead of AddForce.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that Animator component on the player causing the issue. Unticking 'Apply root motion' seems solved my problem but now when player pushing back smoothly, its jittering.